# Displaying tensors

Tags: output-formatting, tensors

I want to display the values of a table with superscirpts and subscripts in a list as bellow.

```
      Superscript[Subscript[R, i], j] = value^i_j
      Superscript[Subscript[R, i], l] = value^i_l
```

A list with columns is also fine.

I run

```
RR := Table[Flatten[ToString[ R[[i, j]], Ricci[[i, j]] }] , {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]]

TableForm[RR]
```

Which displays symbols like

```
R[i,j]
```

Using

```
 Subscript[R, i]^j
```

in place of

```
R[[i, j]]
```

does not display the upper index R^1.

Moreover, using Subscript[R, i j] reads the product "i*j," while I want to avoid the comma in

```
 Subscript[R, i,j]
```

Also, I tried

```
  For[i := 1, i < 5, i++,
   Print[Subscript[R, i,i], "=", ricci[[i, i]]]]
```

How can I get rid of the comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Subscript[R, Row[{#, " ", #}]] & /@ Range@5
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    Table[Superscript[Subscript[R, i], j], {i, 1, 3}, {j, 1, 
   3}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Have fun!

Comment: Sorry, I crafted my question poorly. It is better now.